# How to drip water with a fertilizer without potential energy: pressure tank? recirculation pump? else?

Tags: watering, irrigation, drip-system

I have a 15m² (161ft²) garden, a 100l (26gal) tank where I will prepare a mix of water and liquid organic fertilizer, a filter, an electro-valve, and drip irrigation as on the photo below (2l/h = 0.5gal/h) and 16mm PE hoses between the tank and the drip.

At the maximum, I can setup the bottom of the tank at a height of 1m (3ft) which leads to 0.1bar (1.5psi) when the tank finishes to empty if I neglect pressure losses.

[image]

Is it enough pressure to actually empty the tank? Will suction do the trick?

If not, what shall I do? I am considering :

1. using a pressure tank, but I am afraid the bladder will not like pH 6.3-6.5 fertilized water. In addition, it may be difficult to empty it completely.

[image]

2. using a recirculation pump like this one (220V 0.5A)

[image]

3. using a watering pump with a pression limiter, which power?

[image]

4. use a dirty water pump with the output adapted to the output of the tank, plus an additional or replacement start relay, and a pression limiter. Drawback is the last 10cm height of water cannot be emptied.

[image]

Comment: Before anything, check if the "electrovalve" works with low pressure. If it has a rotating ball inside it should be good. Those hoses look like plasticized pvc.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have been aware of that, I choosed a motorized one.